# Replace Delimiter when exporting to file from Hive

Tags: export, delimiter, hive

When doing an `INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY` is it possible to specify the delimiter to use?

For Columns, Collections, Maps, Arrays... The whole gambit of delimiter uses.

A document or such that shows how to implement would be super best fantastic. :)

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to use concat and only one field if the default line delimiter \n suits you :

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY 'output'
SELECT concat(coalesce(field1,''),'\;',
        coalesce(field2,''),'\;',
        coalesce(field3,''),'\;',
        coalesce(field4,''))
FROM MyTable;
```

that way you won't have default \001 field delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

There's a ticket for this on the Hive Jira. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-634.

Answer (score 1):

use a query like

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/home/sumit/POC/code/UseCase1' select day, " ",
count(distinct(feature)) from Table_Day_Feature group by day order by day;
```

to insert a " " between the columns